# "Multi dimensional" JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I can create a jquery object inline like this (this code is working)

```
$('#tip').qtip({
            content: el.REASON,
            position: {
                corner: {
                    target: 'rightMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
                }
            },
            style: {
                tip: {
                     corner: 'leftMiddle',
                },
                border: {
                    radius: 11,
                    width: 4
                },
                name: 'red'
            },
            show: {
                ready: true, 
                effect: { type: 'slide' }
             },
            hide: {
                when: { target: jq, event: 'click' },
                        effect: function() {
                             $(this).fadeTo(200, 0);
                        }
            }
        })
```

now I want to move this JSON to a function, because I have multiple constructors in my code (this code is not working)

```
function qtipJSON(el, jq) {
    return
        {
            content: el.REASON,
            position: {
                corner: {
                    target: 'rightMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
                }
            },
            style: {
                tip: {
                     corner: 'leftMiddle',
                },
                border: {
                    radius: 11,
                    width: 4
                },
                name: 'red'
            },
            show: {
                ready: true, 
                effect: { type: 'slide' }
             },
            hide: {
                when: { target: jq, event: 'click' },
                        effect: function() {
                             $(this).fadeTo(200, 0);
                       }
            }
        }   
};

$('#tip')(qtipJSON(el, qj))
```

My error is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

I've noticed that it's because of nested jsons.

WORKING:

```
function a(){
return {sdasda:'asda',sdasd:'asdas'}
}

for(i in a()){
document.write(i)
}
```

ALSO WORKING:

```
function a(){
return {sdasda:'asda',sdasd:'asdas', aa:{sds:'1212', sddss:'2222'}}
}

for(i in a()){
document.write(i)
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON, it's an object literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this

```
return
        {
            content: el.REASON,
            ...
```

by this:

```
return  {
            content: el.REASON,
            ...
```

and welcome to the club of people injured by JS semicolon injection.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot end a line with `return` if you want to return an object literal because of implicit semicolon injection.

By moving the opening left brace to the same line as the return it will work.

Here is a slight tweak of what you have: http://jsfiddle.net/FqCVD/   (I made some string literals to compensate for undefined variables).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your final example is a missing : after aa. It should be

```
return {sdasda:'asda',sdasd:'asdas', aa: {sds:'1212', sddss:'2222'}}
```

Your function function qtipJSON(el, jq) is missing a semicolon at the end of the return.

As others have mentioned, the problem is the 'return' keyword on a line by itself. When you have a problem like this one try [JSLint](http://jslint.com/). It would have reported this error.

Comment: You are right, I had typo there. About your third line: I think it should be fixed in another way

Answer (score -1):

javascript will assume you forgot a semi-column and give you this:

```
return {;
    par: 'val'
});
```

Which won't work. What you should do is wrap your return value/object in parenthesis, like this:

```
return ({
    par: 'val'
});
```

Comment: Hmm. Fairly sure you don't need to do that. If your return is on a line by itself it will choke, but no need to put parens around braces.